# Publishing map with GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, publishing

I don't know why the users that visit my website cannot see the map i have published with geoserver.
The steps i took to do this have been:

- importing the data to geoserver
- adding the layers to geoexplorer
- i have changed the style a little
- hit publish map on the geoexplorer
- selected the tools i want to have - next
- copied the link that i need to copy in the webpage
- changed from localhost to the name of my pc
- pasted the code in my webpage.
- i can see the page with the map frame, but the visitors cannot.
  the error they get is:

> the server refused the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide any information about your website location, but something didn't fit in this equation:

```
changed from localhost to the name of my pc
```

If your website is hosted somewhere on the web then your users must use a `domain name` to visit it, or a `public ip` of your computer.

Therefore, I suggest you to change `localhost` with `your domain name` or with the `public ip` instead of the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps passing the url to a web mapping javascript library and you haven't sorted out CORS filtering?